# What do we call functions that are definable by expressions?

Tags: logic, terminology, universal-algebra

Let $X$ denote a model of an algebraic theory $T$. What do we call the functions $f : X^n \rightarrow X$ that are definable by some expression in the language of $T$?

e.g. If $S_3$ is the symmetric group, then the function $f : S_3 \rightarrow S_3$ defined by $f(x,y) = xyyx$ is definable by the expression $xyyx$, and also by the expression $xyyyy^{-1}x$.

Comment: In general, a *function* $f : X^n \rightarrow X$ is called "operation" (e.g.the "sum" $+ : \mathbb N^2 \rightarrow \mathbb N$). A function $f$ is definable in the language $\mathcal L$ of a theory $T$ when there is a formula $\varphi(x_1, ... x_n, y)$ such that : (i) $\forall y \forall z (\varphi(x_1, ... x_n, y) \land \varphi(x_1, ... x_n, z) \rightarrow y = z)$ and (ii) $T \vdash \varphi(x_1, ... x_n, y)$ iff $f(x_1, ... x_n)=y$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, that's not the concept I'm trying to ask about. You're definition is "definability by a formula." I want to know about "definability by an expression." e.g. writing $S_3$ for the symmetric group, the function $f : S_3 \rightarrow S_3$ given by $f(x,y) = xyyx$ is definable by the expression $xyyx$, as well as by the expression $xyyy^{-1}yx$.

Comment: You could say "element of the [clone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_%28algebra%29) generated by $X$ as a $T$-model"...

Comment: In universal algebra, such a function is called a term operation, I believe.

Comment: Eran is right.  See also: page 68 and 69 of [Burris and Sankappanavar](http://www.cs.elte.hu/~ewkiss/univ-algebra.pdf).

Comment: Eran is right, but people who actively work with them (that means, they consider the totality of them for a given algebra) call them simply "operations". I felt confused for a while $n$ years ago when I was trying to follow a talk about constraint satisfaction problem, I did not understand what "group operations" means.